# Webapp en PHP funciona localmente pero en live server no

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Como dice el titulo, tengo una webapp en PHP (no hecha por mi), esta funciona correctamente montada en un servidor local (en XAMPP), el problema esta en que cuando lo subo al live server una seccion y otras cosas dejan de funcionar o no se muestran como deberian, ya hice varias pruebas y note que la seccion en especifico que no muestra nada, esta no regresa respuesta de JSON y creo tener dos posibles culpables,

1. que la solicitud para traer la informacion el servidor no sabe interpretar la informacion o no se convierte correctamente a type JSON
2. o que sea un problema de Jquery
3. que halla algun problema con las request del ajax (tarda a veces en cargar la info, por lo que es una posibilidad)
4. O que halla un bug en el codigo

Cheque varias veces el código y creo esta correctamente escrito (se PHP muy básico), no hay ningún fallo entre la conexión de la Bd con el sistema tampoco, por lo que no se exactamente que es lo que este impidiendo que el server muestre la información correctamente, anexe fotos de lo que deberia mostrarme y esta es la parte del código que creo es la culpable que los requests no se hagan correctamente.

```html
function llenarNivel (idUsuario) {

 $('#loadingIcon').show();
 $.ajax({
  url:'../controller/persona.php',
  data: {'get':'buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario', 'datos':idUsuario},
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result){
   if(result.opStatus == "error"){
    console.log({"msg" : "error", "data" : result});
    $('#car_container').html("");
    $('#loadingIcon').hide();
   } else {
    var elements = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    
     var imgFile = "";
     
     if(result[i].FotoPerfil && result[i].FotoPerfil != "default.png"){ 
      imgFile = "../core/files/profiles/"+ pad(result[i].IdUsuario,5) +"/images/" + result[i].FotoPerfil;
      
     } else {
      result[i].FotoPerfil = "default.png";
      var imgFile = "../core/files/profiles/images/" + result[i].FotoPerfil;
      
     }
     
     elements += "<div onClick='itemClick(this);' class='item img_level div-square2' idUsuario='"+
             result[i].IdUsuario + "' id='"+ 
             result[i].IdUsuario + "'>"+
             "<span style=\"background: url('"+ imgFile +"') no-repeat center; background-size: contain; display: inline-block;\" class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4'>&nbsp;</span>" +
             "<p class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'><span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Nombre: " + 
             result[i].NombreCompleto +"</span> <span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Plaza: "+ 
             result[i].Ciudad + "</span> <span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Correo: " + 
             result[i].Correo + "</span> <span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Contacto: " + 
             ((!result[i].Telefono)  ? result[i].Celular : result[i].Telefono) + "</span></p></div>";
    }
    
    $('#car_container').html("<div class='owl-carousel'>" + elements + "</div>");
    
    
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
     responsive: {
      0: {
       items: 1
      },
      800: {
       items: 2
      },
      1024: {
       items: 4
      }
     }
    });
    $('#loadingIcon').hide();
   }
  },
  error: function(result){
   console.log(result);
  }
 });
}
```

subí una copia por si quieren hacer pruebas http://test.multicomercialdelnorte.com/activate/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://pastebin.com/2y6T1C3i

```
#TRAE LA INFO DEL ARBOL GENEALOGICO DE CADA USUARIO
public function buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario($datos) {

        $idUsuario = $datos;

        $qry = "SELECT
                        u.Id                                        AS IdUsuario,
                        u.NumeroPatrocinador        AS ReferenciaPatrocinador,
                        u.Posicion AS Posicion,
                        CONCAT(
                            p.Nombres, ' ',
                            p.ApellidoPaterno, ' ',
                            p.ApellidoMaterno)      AS NombreCompleto,
                        p.CorreoElectronico         AS Correo,
                        p.Telefono                          AS Telefono,
                        c.Nombre                            AS Ciudad,
                        p.Celular                               AS Celular,
                        t.Nombre                            AS TipoSuscripcion,
                        i.Nombre                                AS FotoPerfil
                        FROM usuario u
                        INNER JOIN tipo t ON u.IdTipoAfiliacion = t.Id
                        INNER JOIN persona p ON u.IdPersona = p.Id
                        INNER JOIN direccion d ON d.IdPersona = p.Id
                        INNER JOIN ciudad c ON c.Id = d.IdCiudad
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN expediente i ON i.IdUsuario = u.Id AND i.IdTipoDocumento = 5
                        WHERE u.IdPatrocinador = $idUsuario AND u.Id NOT IN($idUsuario)";

        $l = new DataLink();

        $r = $l->runQuery($qry, "SELECT");

        return $r;
    }



function buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario($datos){

    $genealogia = array();
    $p = new Persona();
    $r = $p->buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario($datos);

    if($r){
        if($r->num_rows > 0){
            while($gen = $r->fetch_assoc()){

                if(!FILE_EXISTS('../core/files/profiles/'.STR_PAD($gen['IdUsuario'],5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).'/images/imgPerf'.STR_PAD($gen['IdUsuario'],5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT).".png")){
                    $gen['FotoPerfil'] = 'default.png';
                }
                $genealogia[] = $gen;
            }
        }

        return $genealogia;
    }
}

case "buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario":
            $genealogia = array();
            $r = buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario($datos);

            if($r){
                $genealogia = $r;

                echo JSON_ENCODE($genealogia);
            } else {
                echo JSON_ENCODE(array("opStatus"=>"error", "message"=>"hubo un error al realizar la consulta."));
            }
            unset($_POST['get']);
            break;
        case "consultarPersonaPorIdUsuario":
            $persona = array();

            $r = consultarPersonaPorIdUsuario($datos);

            if($r){
                $persona = $r;

                echo JSON_ENCODE($persona);
            } else {
                echo JSON_ENCODE(array("opStatus"=>"error", "message"=>"hubo un error al realizar la consulta."));
            }
            unset($_POST['get']);
            break;



JAVASCRIPT

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var idUsuario = getCookie('i');

    llenarPatrocinador(idUsuario);
    llenarNivel(idUsuario);
});

function llenarPatrocinador(idUsuario){
    var idPadre = getCookie('i');
    $.ajax({
        url:'../controller/persona.php',
        data: {'get':'consultarPersonaPorIdUsuario', 'datos':{'IdUsuario':idUsuario}},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            if(result.opStatus == "error") {
            } else {
                if(result.Imagen){
                    $('#img_headLevel')
                    .css("background","url('../core/files/profiles/"+result.preFile+"/images/"+result.Imagen+"') no-repeat center")
                    .css("background-size","contain");
                    $('#btn_back').attr("IdPadre",idPadre);
                } else {
                    $('#img_headLevel')
                    .css("background","url('../core/files/profiles/images/default.png') no-repeat center")
                    .css("background-size","contain");
                    $('#btn_back').attr("IdPadre",idPadre);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

function llenarNivel(idUsuario){

    $('#loadingIcon').show(); 
    $.ajax({
        url:'../controller/persona.php',
        data: {'get':'buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario', 'datos':idUsuario},
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            if(result.opStatus == "error"){
                console.log({"msg" : "error", "data" : result});
                $('#car_container').html("");
                $('#loadingIcon').hide();
            } else {
                var elements = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

                    var imgFile = "";

                    if(result[i].FotoPerfil && result[i].FotoPerfil != "default.png"){  
                        imgFile = "../core/files/profiles/"+ pad(result[i].IdUsuario,5) +"/images/" + result[i].FotoPerfil;

                    } else {
                        result[i].FotoPerfil = "default.png";
                        var imgFile = "../core/files/profiles/images/" + result[i].FotoPerfil;

                    }

                    elements += "<div onClick='itemClick(this);' class='item img_level div-square2' idUsuario='"+
                                           result[i].IdUsuario + "' id='"+ 
                                           result[i].IdUsuario + "'>"+
                                           "<span style=\"background: url('"+ imgFile +"') no-repeat center; background-size: contain; display: inline-block;\" class='col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4'>&nbsp;</span>" +
                                           "<p class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'><span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Nombre: " + 
                                           result[i].NombreCompleto +"</span> <span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Plaza: "+ 
                                           result[i].Ciudad + "</span> <span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Correo: " + 
                                           result[i].Correo + "</span> <span class='col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>Contacto: " + 
                                           ((!result[i].Telefono)  ? result[i].Celular : result[i].Telefono) + "</span></p></div>";
                }

                $('#car_container').html("<div class='owl-carousel'>" + elements + "</div>");


                $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                    responsive: {
                        0: {
                            items: 1
                        },
                        800: {
                            items: 2
                        },
                        1024: {
                            items: 4
                        }
                    }
                });
                $('#loadingIcon').hide();
            }
        },
        error: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}

function pad(num, size) {
    var s = "00000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-size);
}

function itemClick(item){
    var idUsuario = item.id;

    llenarPatrocinador(idUsuario);
    llenarNivel(idUsuario);
    $('#btn_back').show('fade');
}


$('#btn_back').click(function(){
    var idUsuario = $(this).attr("IdPadre");
    llenarPatrocinador(idUsuario);
    llenarNivel(idUsuario);
    $('#btn_back').hide('fade');
});

$('#car_left').click(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});

$('#car_right').click(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin ver el codigo ni los errores es muy dificil ayudarte. Adjuntar links no es algo que se deba hacer, el codigo relevante debe estar en la pregunta. Mira [ask]

Comment: ya agregue la parte del codigo que creo es la conflictiva, una disculpa soy nuevo aqui

Comment: hermano censuraste la URL y dejaste la IP visible....

Comment: debajo de la URL intenta poner esto: `async:false` sentiras que la pagina no responde hasta que tenga respuesta del servidor. sea una respuesta correcta o nula.

Comment: te refieres a $.ajax({
  url:'../controller/persona.php',
  data: {'get':'buscarGenealogiaPorIdUsuario', 'datos':idUsuario},
  type: 'POST', en el .php o en el navegador?

Comment: revisa que las versiones de php y los permisos o librerías que estan ejecutándose en el xammp sean los mismos que están en el servidor, suele pasar que algunas librerías estan sin activar y puede ocurrir ese tipo de problemas.

Comment: En ninguna parte de tu código veo el encabezado del formato JSON, intenta agregando `header('Content-Type: application/json');` antes de cada `echo` (Solo escribelo una vez, al iniciar el código si te es prudente) también intenta cambiar `JSON_ENCODE` por `json_encode` considero eso puede solucionarlo. Ahora como recomendación, monta tu server en WAMP, en mi poco expertise he notado mucho mejor perfomance en este.